# Validating user in Azure Mobile App Against Exiting User Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I am writing my first Azure Mobile App and I want to implement "Custom Authentication" against an existing websites user database.

In the existing ASP.Net website I have the usual dbo.AspNetUsers tables etc.

I cannot work out how to call this existing website to authenticate a user.

I have the following code but I am lost how to get the isValidAssertion function to talk to my existing user database from within the Axure Mobile App.

It would be the equivalent of this line found in the website..

```
ApplicationSignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
```

So, I have the following code:

```
private static bool isValidAssertion(JObject assertion)
    {
        // this is where I want to call the existing user database

        // this is how it's done in the MVC website
        //ApplicationSignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);

        return true;
    }

    public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] JObject assertion)
    {
        if (isValidAssertion(assertion)) // user-defined function, checks against a database
        {
            JwtSecurityToken token = AppServiceLoginHandler.CreateToken(new Claim[] { new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, (string)assertion["username"]) },
                mySigningKey,
                myAppURL,
                myAppURL,
                TimeSpan.FromHours(24));
            return Ok(new LoginResult()
            {
                AuthenticationToken = token.RawData,
                User = new LoginResultUser() { UserId = (string)assertion["username"] }
            });
        }
        else // user assertion was not valid
        {
            return ResponseMessage(Request.CreateUnauthorizedResponse());
        }
    }
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use `Asp.Net Identity` for this.

Basically you need to create `BaseApiController` to get `OWIN` Context first:

```
public class BaseApiController : ApiController
{ 
    private ApplicationUserManager _appUserManager = null;
    protected ApplicationUserManager AppUserManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _appUserManager ?? Request.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your custom authentication controller need to inherit from `BaseApiController`:

```
[MobileAppController]
public class CustomAuthController : BaseApiController
{
   private static bool isValidAssertion(JObject assertion)
   {
       var username = assertion["username"].Value<string>();
       var password = assertion["password"].Value<string>(); 

       //Validate user using FindAsync() method
       var user = await this.AppUserManager.FindAsync(username, password);
       return (user != null);
    }
}
```

You will also need to init `OWIN` context in `Startup class`:

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(UPARMobileApp.Startup))]

namespace UPARMobileApp
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureOWinContext(app);
            ConfigureMobileApp(app);            
        }
    }
}

public static void ConfigureOWinContext(IAppBuilder app)
{
    // Configure the db context and user manager to use a single instance per request
    app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
}
```

More information about how to setup `ApplicationDbContext`, `ApplicationUserManager` and OWIN configuration can be read from here:
http://bitoftech.net/2015/01/21/asp-net-identity-2-with-asp-net-web-api-2-accounts-management/